# Как отправить и получить ajax запрос

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Пытаюсь третий день найти способ решения своей проблемы, но никак не могу выйти из неё.
Мне нужно, чтобы при клике на `div (из кода под номером 1)` у меня открывалась и сортировалась таблица уже в `label (из кода под номером 2)` в базе данных с названием таблицы `teacher` по ключу `faculty`.
контент ключа `faculty` меняется в зависимости от нажатой кнопки

вот пример пары кнопок `номер 1`

```html
<div class="other-fac">

  <label class="Fac_of_tr_and_technology stateg content-full active">

    <div class="content-text-logo">
    
      <span class="nav-bar-text-width int-regular-14px f-white">Факультет 1</span>
                                    
    </div>
        
  </label>
  
  <label class="Add_education stateg content-full non-active">

    <div class="content-text-logo">
    
      <span class="nav-bar-text-width int-regular-14px f-white">Факультет 2</span>
                                    
    </div>
        
  </label>
  
</div>
```

вот пример обработки данных из получаемой базы данных `номер 2`

```html
<label class="statet teacher-area non-active">

  <div class="name-pic-teacher">

    <img src="<?php echo $teacher["img"]; ?>" class="teacher-photo"/>

      <span class="teacher-name-surname f-white int-medium-16px">
        <span id="name"><?php echo $teacher["name"]; ?></span>
        <span id="surname"><?php echo $teacher["surname"]; ?></span>
      </span>

  </div>

</label>
```

В ajax я не силён, но всеми силами пытаюсь победить и изучить. Если кто-то мог бы помочь с кодом - был бы вам очень благодарен

Comment: при чем тут ajax? я что-то пропустил. Я тут верстку только вижу...у вас endpoint есть куда вы будете запросы присылать и которые вам учителей возвращать будут?

Comment: чтобы отсылать запрос на сервер и в динамическом варианте брать нужные записи массива из сортировки. как-то так я себе это представляю. Выше да, записи верстки на которые надо накинуть данный запрос. не могу понять как это сделать

Comment: Примеры кода и всё необходимое есть в документации. Выбери, что нравится, копируй код, пробуй.. [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) | [XMLHttpRequest-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) | [Using XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)